# Chrome messaging - showing data instead of fixed message

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to make cloud messaging server, which sends notifications to chrome (PC and mobile). 
I found https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/codelabs/push-notifications/ and tutorial works.

In this tutorial there is a listener:

```
self.addEventListener('push', function(event) {
  console.log('[Service Worker] Push Received.');
  console.log(`[Service Worker] Push had this data: "${event.data.text()}"`);

  const title = 'Push Codelap';
  const options = {
    body: 'Yay it works.',
    icon: 'images/icon.png',
    badge: 'images/badge.png'
  };

  event.waitUntil(self.registration.showNotification(title, options));
});
```

And it works - when I send 'Hello world' through https://web-push-codelab.appspot.com/ it appears... but only in console.log.

How to change the options to get `${event.data.text()}` intead of `Yay it works`?

I tried to change `body: 'Yay it works.',` into  `body: ${event.data.text()},`

but `Syntax Error: Unexpected token {` appears.

Comment: You need to use string template `${event.data.text()}`

Comment: @Hosar this causes Syntax Error: Unexpected token {

Answer (score 1):

The best what I did yesterday is go to sleep. Fresh mind and solution is comming immediately.

```
  const options = {
    body:  event.data.text(),
    icon: 'images/icon.png',
    badge: 'images/badge.png'
  };
```